# Need help locating CPP files that were excluded from project in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019

I have been using Visual Studios 2019 as my IDE to learn C++ in school for a little over a month now. I often create new CPP files for practice or class lab work which means I have multiple CPP files in a single solution.

I have learned you can 'exclude' CPP files from the solution to allow you to run other CPP files when testing or debugging a program. However I know this isn't a perfect way to do this because it seems that the IDE will often completely remove the files from the solution explorer leaving me with no way to include them back into the solution.

I have set the solution explorer to list all files and have seen the files stay in the solution explorer with the file name still listed with a little 'do not enter' symbol over the file icon to indicate it is not a part of the solution anymore. This is fine as it allows me to right click and interact with the file at will which in turn allows me to include or exclude the file without issue.

I have had so many different and weird issues when doing this but the question I want answered right now is how can I prevent a CPP file (or any file for that matter) from utterly disappearing out of the solution explorer?

Comment: I found some of them, they were under `D:\Home\my_project\`.  I'm going open up File Explorer on the C drive and enter the search pattern, "*.cpp".  It will take a while on the 1TB drive.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a different workflow: create multiple projects within your solution.

Use menu File -> Add -> New Project...

Follow the wizard (likely - `Console App`), name it as something you can recognize (`Lab1`, for example).

Now you can select any of your projects in the Solution Explorer and use `Set as a Startup Project` in the context menu.

This allows you to browse your entire code easily, copy/paste (I don't endorse that :) ), and run/debug the active project.